# High voltage on input pin of op amp

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

I'm building a linear powersupply with op amp LM324, but I'm having a problem with this op amp, it's constantly outputing 6~8 V on the + input, even with only Vcc and GND connected (20 V). This is a problem because I want to control this voltage (around 0 to 5 V), but with the input pin at 6~8 V I can't do this.

Comment: Why do you say you can't? The input pins are high-impedance, but they have to have *some* voltage. It's likely it just floats to some fraction of the supply voltage. What happens if you try to drive it?

Comment: Show us a schematic.

Answer (score 2):

The input pins of the LM324 have a small bias current flowing out of them. Some op-amps have current that flows into the input, and some have a bias current that may flow in or out and may change sign for various reasons. Some op-amps have nasty (relatively) high current pulses that flow in or out of them at some kHz.

Whatever the situation, you cannot leave the op-amp input open if you want the op-amp to operate normally. In the case of the LM324 typically 40 or 50nA will flow out. A suitable resistance to your desired bias voltage can 'tame' this bias current. Different op-amps may have bias currents from fA to uA, but they all have this same characteristic.